# C#, Multiline textBox lines validation

Tags: c#, frameworks

I want to know how can I make a multiline textBox line validation... 
My problem is that I have a multiline textBox and I have a TCP Server and Client, so the client is constantly sending messages to the server... and I have the Multiline textbox to see those messages... 
I just want to know how can I put the maximum lenght of lines on 100 or 200, and the old messages gets erased only from textbox.

In short, I want the text box to erase the old lines and continue showing new messages.

Hope you can help me.

I have this code but when it reaches 100 it just stops and I don't want to stop the multilne textbox Lines.

```
int _lineCount = 1;
        List<string> lines = txtChat.Lines.ToList();
        if (lines.Count >= _lineCount)
        {
            for (int i = _lineCount - 1; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                //Split the line when it has more then 100 characters
                if (lines[i].Length <= 100)
                {
                    string line = lines[i];
                    lines[i] = line.Substring(0, 100);
                    lines.Insert(i + 1, line.Substring(100, line.Length - 100));
                    MessageBox.Show(line);
                }
            }
            //Re-assign the lines
            txtChat.Lines = lines.ToArray();
            //Set the cursor to the end of the text
            txtChat.SelectionStart = txtChat.Text.Length;
            //Set new line count.
            _lineCount = txtChat.Lines.Length;
        }
```